# send email using php with AWS EC2

Tags: php, apache, sendmail

I use AWS EC2 server (ubuntu instance) and I want to send email through php code

I installed sendmail and modify .mc file as blow

---

```
FEATURE(`no_default_msa')dnl 
dnl DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Family=inet6, Name=MTA-v6, Port=smtp, Addr=::1')dnl 
DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Family=inet, Name=MTA-v4, Port=smtp, Addr=127.0.0.1')dnl 
dnl DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Family=inet6, Name=MSP-v6, Port=submission, M=Ea, Addr=::1')dnl 
DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Family=inet, Name=MSP-v4, Port=submission, M=Ea, Addr=127.0.0.1')dnl
```

---

I removed Addr and restart sendmail service

but, I cannot send an email.

I tested sendmail on console (sendmail to@mail.com from@mail.com)

and php file like php sendmailtest.php.

both of them work!

but, it still doesn't work when I tried with browser. ( like http://test.com/sendmail.php )

here is my apache log

```
sh: 1: sendmail: not found 
[Thu Apr 25 03:40:53 2013] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] xxx@gmail.com 
[Thu Apr 25 03:40:54 2013] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
```

update

here is my test code to send email

```
 $mailto="xxxxxxxx@gmail.com";
 $subject="mail test";
 $content="test";
 $result=mail($mailto, $subject, $content);
 if($result){
    echo "mail success";
 }else  {
    error_log($mailto, 0);  
    echo "mail fail";
 }
```

Thanks in advance,

---

Solved this problem.

I should input /usr/sbin/sendmail

I don't know why another location doesn't work even there exists sendmail.

Comment: Post your PHP code to send the mail.

Answer (score 0):

Use the absolute path to sendmail, when running from a script your PATH is often not setup.

Comment: from the command line type:   "which sendmail"   use the full output of that command.

Comment: but when I send an email through sendmail, it works fine wherever I command

Comment: I also changed sendmail pah as sendmail_path: /usr/share/sendmail/sendmail -t -i but still not working

Comment: Solved. absolute path to sendmail. but /usr/share/sendmail/sendmail it not working, only with /usr/sbin/sendmail. I don't why :(